# how filter view url in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, url, asp.net-mvc-4

I override AuthorizeCore function in mvc for authentication and authorization this working fine when I call a view form controller. but now i have a view that contain some links for reports i want to show report to users that has access rights. I can hide links of reports but unable to restrict direct url.

fine with this url request [http://MyDomain:1426/Company/Index] but
not goes to authorizecore method when url is : [http://MyDomain:1426/Reports/GrpView?OfferID=1] (because I have no controller for reports) 
is there any way in MVC to filter view urls ?

Comment: How do you mean "restrict direct URL"? Do you mean stopping users entering the URL into the browser and accessing that way?

Comment: I actually want to show error page you are unable to see this report. problem is i case of view, AuthorizeCore method not called. I register it in global file.

Comment: yes i am using AuthorizeAttribute and override its AuthorizeCore method.

Comment: The AuthorizeAttribute will *only* work on Controllers action methods. What is providing the reporting? Reporting services? If you need to restrict access you would have to it within the provider of the reports. MVC cannot filter URLs it does not service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what the `Reports/GrpView` handler that is providing your reporting functionality is. It doesn't seem to be an ASP.NET MVC controller action as you would have decorated it with the `[Authorize]` attribute and specified the roles.

If this is some legacy WebForms page or a handler you could use the `<location>` section in your `web.config` to control access:

```
<location path="Reports/GrpView">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <!-- deny access to all users -->
            <deny users="*"/> 

            <!-- allow access to users in the "admins" role -->
            <allow roles="admins"/> 
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

The `Authorize` attribute (and any custom attributes deriving from it) are intended to be used only to secure access to ASP.NET MVC controller actions. If you are not using ASP.NET MVC for your reporting services you cannot use those mechanisms.

Comment: GrpView is my .aspx file. complete path of this file is views/reports/grpview.aspx I write router to access this file. now i take a approach to solve this i create controller by this controller i try to access file Views/Reports/GrapView.aspx  but unable to open report. is their any way to access a .aspx page in mvc ?

Comment: Why is this ASPX page in your Views folder? Files inside this folder can be served only with controller actions. You cannot have classic WebForms pages there. So you must have a controller called `ReportsController` with an action called `GrpView` that you could decorate with the `[Authorize(Roles="admins")]` attribute. If on the other hand this is a classic WebForms page you need to move it away from the Views folder and then specify its path in the `<location>` element in your web.config.

Comment: as I have webforms pages i move them in other folder 'AllReports' now everyone can access these files and view reports by changing just id from url. I try to make un-accessible using but not succeeded <location path="~/AllReports/GrpView.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

Comment: Try like this: `<location path="AllReports">...</location>`. Or even better you could place a web.config file inside the `AllReports` folder and then use `<location path="">...</location>`.

Comment: thanks Darin Dimitrov it works. if i <deny users="*"/> this deny all the users i put <allow users="abdulwahe"/> then <deny users="*"/> this not works for user abdulwahe ? i am not using asp user management i manage my own. how config file able to see which user is logged in ?

Answer (score 0):

My report is on .aspx page and I put it into Reporting view folder (bad approach). as darin dimitrov says 
Why is this ASPX page in your Views folder? Files inside this folder can be served only with controller actions. You cannot have classic WebForms pages there. So you must have a controller called ReportsController with an action called GrpView that you could decorate with the [Authorize(Roles="admins")] attribute. If on the other hand this is a classic WebForms page you need to move it away from the Views folder and then specify its path. by using this approach I am unable to pass my call form AuthorizeCore  function.

///
I handle role rights management on my .aspx page. if anybody find any other solution then please share.